# Material Design Angular 5 mat-autocomplete in absolute position without the use of formControl

Tags: angular, material-design

I am trying to replace a custom suggestion menu I had built in the past, with mat-autocomplete.. Unfortunately I can't get it to work without clicking on it's attached `matInput`. Here is what I have right now:

```xml
<div id="connection-editor" class="resizable"
     contenteditable="true">
</div>
<mat-form-field>
<input matInput type="text" placeholder="Add type..." aria-label="Number" [formControl]="atQuery" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete
    [style.position]="absolute"
    [style.left]="suggestX + 'px'"
    [style.top]="suggestY + 'px'" #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let entry of entities" [value]="entry.name" (onSelectionChange)="onEntrySelect(entry)">
    {{ entry.name }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

I am updating `atQuery` based on interactions at the `contenteditable` and the object `entities` is being populated correctly..

```js
this.atQuery.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400)
        .subscribe(query => {
            this.connectionService.queryEntries(query).subscribe(text => {
                const suggestions: SuggestionJson[] = <SuggestionJson[]> JSON.parse(text).content;
                if (suggestions.length === 1) {
                    const suggestion: SuggestionJson = suggestions[0];
                    this.users = suggestion.users.map((e) => e.complex);
                    this.entities = suggestion.entities.map((e) => e.complex);
                    this.primitives = suggestion.primitives.filter((e) => !e.value).map((e) => {
                        const pr: PrimitiveEntryJson  = new PrimitiveEntryJson();
                        pr.value = e.value;
                        pr.type = e.type;
                        return pr;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

I used to have two variables `suggestX` and `suggestY` that would position the suggestion menu under the text cursor.

Right now `mat-autocomplete` results appear only when I click on the input that has `[formControl]`. I want to be controlling when they appear so it can work with absolute positioning.

Any way to use `mat-autocomplete` in absolute position without input (or hidden input) and `formControl` by just passing a query as text?